# adding a site to Apache2 Ubuntu Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am trying to add a webiste on Ubunutu Linux server and following this tutorial http://www.hostly.com/hosting-info/build-website-using-apache-1658.html

- Created a webconfiguration file /etc/apache2/sites-available and it looks like this

  ```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
  # Basic setup
  ServerName analys.ideometrics.se
  DocumentRoot /home/micke/www/analys.ideometrics/
  # Logfiles
  ErrorLog  /home/micke/wwwlogs/apache2/error.log
  CustomLog /home/micke/wwwlogs/apache2/access.log combined
  </VirtualHost>
  ```
- created a index.html in the location /home/micke/www/analys.ideometrics/
- restarted apache webserver

when I am trying to access the URL (analys.ideometrics.se), getting internal error. I am not sure, if have to edit host file.

Can you please give me a clue.

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: Error : 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Internal server errors can mean a few different things. It looks like there is an error somewhere in the webserver configuration. Just check your logs (/home/micke/wwwlogs/apache2/error.log) to see what's causing the 500.

Comment: I checked in log file, it didn't have any info about my http request.

Answer (score 3):

Did you follow step 7 of the guide you posted? 
Say your config file is `/etc/apache2/sites-available/ideometrics`, you must enable it using:

```
sudo a2ensite ideometrics
```

This creates a symlink in sites-enabled, which you can see by typing:

```
ls -l /etc/apache2/sites-enabled
```

It should read something like this:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 27 Sep 28 10:51 ideometrics -> ../sites-available/ideometrics
```

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Comment: It's unfortunate the OP has never come back to accept this answer.

Answer (score -1):

Put the VHost file in /sites-enabled and then restart apache.